# Any lightweight image editor without X

Tags: image, software-recommendation

down vote
favorite
I'm new to modern Linux (but not a beginner in programming).

I want to create a light weight coding box on a Raspberry Pi. With just command line tools and Love2D (built on SDL2).

I managed to install PiLove, based on Jessie (http://pilove.mitako.eu/) and it's perfect.

I can run my Love2D games without X and I use JED as code editor.

I now need an image/sprite editor.

I cannot find anything, like Love2D that can run without X. I'm surprised it not exists.

Any idea?

I tried Aseprite with no success.

My last solution will be to create a simple sprite editor in Love2D :)

Comment: Do not cross-post https://askubuntu.com/questions/1011793/any-image-editor-for-raspberry-without-x

Comment: It's not a cross-post, my other post was tagged as "off topic" because not on the right page. Now I deleted the post.

Comment: You may want to add the word "interactive" to your question, if that's what you're after.

Answer (score 2):

The image's God under linux is called

> Imagemagick

You can do everything you want with image with it using only command line (no require of X at all)

Comment: There's also the drop-in replacement GraphicsMagick, which has some added features.